# After upgrade to Grails 2.4.3 from 2.2.4, metaclass changes are not reset between tests during unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

We are attempting to upgrade from Grails 2.2.4 to 2.4.3.  In Grails 2.2.4 if I included GrailsUnitTestMixin for my unit tests, metaClass changes were reset between tests. In 2.4.3, this behavior doesn't seem to be working anymore, and my tests are failing.  In looking at the latest code for GrailsUnitTestMixin, I no longer see a reference to MetaClassRegistryCleaner.

Has this behavior changed since 2.2.4? What is the appropriate way to make sure metaClass changes during unit tests are discarded after the test?

I'm aware of the Spock @ConfineMetaclassChanges annotation for limiting scope of particular changes, but the previous behavior in 2.2.4 was much more convenient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The unit test support in Grails 2.4.x has been refactored. There are some notes about this in the ["What new in Grails 2.4"](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/introduction.html#whatsNew24) guide. Docs are in the [unit testing guide](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#unitTesting).

MetaClass cleaning is done after each test class by default.
Source code is in 
https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-testing/src/main/groovy/grails/test/runtime/MetaClassCleanerTestPlugin.groovy

In Grails 2.4.3, a fix was made which affected metaclass cleaning of Grails artefacts. Previously this was done after the execution of each test method:
https://github.com/grails/grails-core/commit/1885351d2be8f74076f2c83edcbc048c5bcfd9d7

Since Grails caches the "test runtime" instance for the execution of all tests in a single test class by default, the metaclass changes don't get cleared after each test method by default.

If you'd like to clear metaclass changes after each test method in the test class, you can annotate the test method with a [FreshRuntime](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.x/api/grails/test/runtime/FreshRuntime.html) annotation. Adding this annotation to the class level should be supported, but that feature is currently broken in Grails 2.4.3 and [the bug](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11626) will be fixed in Grails 2.4.4 . This is fixed by this commit:
https://github.com/grails/grails-core/commit/27ceeb086baeb879c490f29f6d799cbd532c0772

In summary, the currently solution is to add the [FreshRuntime](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.x/api/grails/test/runtime/FreshRuntime.html) annotation to each test method. After [GRAILS-11626](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11626) is fixed in Grails 2.4.4, you can then use the annotation at the classlevel.